# Submit form after text is inserted

Tags: javascript, forms, autocomplete, submit, mootools

I have a Mootools autosuggest script, that is triggered by a dropdown of user results. When I click a result, I can not figure out how to auto-submit the form to results page upon clicking a suggested result. I have spent over an hour trying out various code from here and other sites, nothing is giving. I would really appreciate a fix. I have jQuery.noConflict and working fully that is not the problem so I can accept code suggested.

Nature of this:

```
<form action='results.php' method='post' name='searchform'>
<input type='text' class='home_signin_field' id='search' name='search' size='30' value="{$search}">
     <div id='suggest' class='suggest'></div>
     <button>sdf</button>
       <input type='hidden' name='s' value='{$s}'>
       <input type='hidden' name='p' value='{$p}'>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
  window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    var options = {
        script:"json_results.php?task=suggest_user&limit=3&",
        varname:"input",
        json:true,
        shownoresults:false,
        maxresults:5,
        multisuggest:false,
        callback: function (obj) { }
    };
    var as_json = new bsn.AutoSuggest('search', options);
  });
//-->
</script>
```

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

This is a dirty way of making it work with a timer, as the only way I can do it. If anyone knows of a better method (mootools please) I would be grateful!

Added `onchange="autosubmit()"` to input field.
Changed `method='POST'` to `method='GET'`

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function autosubmit() {
        setTimeout("document.search_form.submit()", 1000);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: It appears that way, tags updated.

Comment: I produced a dirty solution that directs to the results, I should mark this as resolved (still not satisfied but it works for now).

Comment: @CodyTapping Please, include your *dirty solution* in the question, and specify what's the auto-suggest script you are using.